# Обязателен ли знак препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Сергей(-)это кто? (Кто такой Сергей?)

Обязателен ли здесь знак препинания?

Comment: "Папа, это мой лучший друг!" - "Очень приятно. А ты кто?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сергей - это кто? Тире ставится в обязательном порядке между подлежащим и сказуемым перед связкой ЭТО и соответствует паузе в устной речи. Это как раз тот случай, когда авторские варианты невозможны.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: А если я к Сергею обращаюсь: "Сергей, это кто?" - и киваю на сидящего в ресторане за соседним столом.

Comment: "Сергей, это кто?" Здесь тире не ставится, ЭТО - подлежащее, КТО - вопросительное местоимение в роли сказуемого, пауза отсутствует.

Comment: А если я сознательно (или неосознанно) делаю паузу: "Сергей, это (в ужасе, невольная пауза) кто-о-о?!" - и показываю на Виеподобное существо в тёмном лесу?